# Big Sans-Serif From Aaron Draplin's Presentation

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Any idea what the big sans-serif is that Aaron Draplin uses for some presentations (in the picture I'm talking about the "GRAPHIC TREASURES"/"AMERICAN UNDERBELLY" font).

WhatTheFont wasn't able to identify it. Thanks!

[image: Image from Draplin's presentation]

Comment: It's got a very strong 'YouWorkForThem' vibe. If an alternative is acceptable, [Industry,](https://www.youworkforthem.com/font/T5020/industry) [Steelworks,](https://www.youworkforthem.com/font/T0932/steelworks) [Revolution Gothic,](https://www.youworkforthem.com/font/T2788/revolution-gothic) and [Filmotype Glenlake](https://www.youworkforthem.com/font/T3392/filmotype-glenlake) all have a similar hard-edged, industrial feel.

Answer (score 2):

I recently emailed him because I too wanted to identify this, this is what Aaron said:

[image: Email Response]